# Vuejs 2 + laravel elixir + lodash Uncaught ReferenceError: _ is not defined

Tags: laravel-5, vuejs2, lodash, laravel-elixir

I'm using the tools specified in the title. I import lodash in my bootstrap.js

```
window._ = require('lodash');
```

However, when I try to use something like this (similar example to [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#debounce-Param-Attribute-for-v-model-removed)), I get the error discribed in the title

```
created() {
   this.test();
},

methods: {
   test: _.debounce(function () {
      console.log('calculating', true);
      setTimeout(function () {
         console.log('calculating', false);
      }.bind(this), 1000)
   }, 500),
}
```

However, if I remove the `window._ = require('lodash');` and insert `lodash` manually in the page it works fine, like

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.13.1/lodash.js"></script>
```

What I'm missing?

Also, What is the advantage of importing the libraries by require instead of using Gulp to merge and uglyfy everything?

Comment: Have you tried just `var _ = require('lodash')`
`

Comment: Sorry, it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you are getting that error related to `_`.

On your other question, I can think following advantage of using `require` over gulp or any other build tool:

- All build tools comes with their own set of dependencies and other accessories, which bloats your overall code size.
- You may start to rely on their plugins and time can come, when you need to use grunt for one task, while for other tasks you are using grunt, quting from [gulp-grunt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-grunt)

> What if your favorite grunt plugin isn't available for gulp yet? Don't fret, there is nothing to worry about! Why don't you just hook in your grunt configuration?

- You will have to manage updating of different plugins of gulp and make sure all are working with new updated versions.

These are some of the things I have experienced or read about, but these tools do remove the pain of building, hot-reloading, compressing or obfuscating your code, but definetely there can be other raw way to do these, as what these are doing is providing you an abstraction.

Comment: Sorry my very late response! I couldn't figure out so far what is happening! I just set up a new Laravel project and it works as expected. But in the old one no! Getting mad... :/